# Distribution of Nilsequences (Iterated Fractional Parts)

Tags: nt.number-theory

After reading a blog entry on nilsequences, I wondered the about how many arithmetic progressions appear in [nilsequences](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/09/25/the-quantitative-behaviour-of-polynomial-orbits-on-nilmanifolds/).

Let $f(n) =  n \sqrt{2} \lfloor n \sqrt{3}  \rfloor $.  How often does $\Delta^3 f(n) = 0$ ?   [Some notes claim](http://math.stanford.edu/~rhoades/FILES/tao040608.pdf) it vanishes 1/16 of the time.

In other words, does
$$ \lim_{N \to \infty}  \frac{\\# \{ 1 \leq n \leq N : f(n) - 3 f(n+r) + 3f(n+2r) - f(n+3r) = 0   \}}{N} $$
have a limit if we fix $r$?  If we do not fix $r$, this difference seems to vanishes 1/3 of the time.

For different fixed $r$, the fraction ($N=100$) the count I got was: $0, 48, 27, 0, 79, 0, 70, 6, 18, 58$

Does this have an interpretation in terms of cocycles over $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: A minor comment: in the nilsequence world, as far as I know when they talk about a.p.'s appearing, they generally don't demand that they should be along consecutive terms of the nilsequence.